# HTTP server gives error when responses some requests

Tags: node.js, express

I am making an express.js server to store pictures.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/*', (request, response) =>
{
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/data' + request.path);
});
app.listen(9999);
console.log('Server started on port 9999');
```

And I have a problem. If I type `http://127.0.0.1:9999/vehicles/boats/dinghy.png` into browser, I get a picture, but when I type `https://127.0.0.1:9999/main/avatar.png` I get `This site can’t provide a secure connection 127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.` Both files do exist, but one of them is sent correctly, but another one gives an error. What can it be caused by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second request is sent via `https`. As you're not providing a valid certificate for localhost at your express app, the browser will give you a hint about this.

Comment: ****, thanks. Did not notice it. Somehow mistyped and did not pay attention to it. thanks s lot.